# join or merge data frames by if value is in one of multiple columns

Tags: r, join, merge

I'd like to join two data frames (`df1` and `df2`) based on if a certain value in `df1` is in one of multiple columns in `df2`.

For example:

```
#create df1
year <- c(2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015)
person1 <- c('sam', 'sarah', 'sally', 'kat', 'ryan', 'sally')
person2 <- c('mike', 'sally', 'ryan', 'sam', 'sam', 'mike')
stocks <- rnorm(6, 50000, 10000)
df1 <- data.frame(year, person1, person2, stocks)

#create df2
year <- c(2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015)
person1 <- c('sam', 'sally', 'sally', 'sam', 'ryan', 'mike')
person2 <- c('mike', 'sarah', 'ryan', 'kat', 'sam', 'sally')
bonds <- rnorm(6, 10000, 1000)
df2 <- data.frame(year, person1, person2, bonds)

#merge attempt
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('year', 'person1'))
```

However, in `df2`, sometimes `person1` and `person2` are switched, so that `df1$person1 == df1$person2`, but the name pair combination is still the same.

Is there a way to join these dfs based on `year` AND if `(df1$person1 == df2$person1 OR df1$person1 == df2$person2)`?

Alternatively, I had considered generating a new variable, `matchup_code` based on the product ASCII codes of the characters in `person1` and `person2` columns and then joining by `c('year', 'matchup_code')`. However, `utf8ToInt()` produces a vector that I can't figure out how to multiply.

Comment: Please post desired output from this example. And use `set.seed()` to reproduce random values.

Answer (score 1):

The parallel min (or max) - `pmin` / `pmax` - can also work on characters so you can create a new column based on that and merge on it, i.e.

```
dplyr::left_join(transform(df1, new_person = pmin(person1, person2)), 
                 transform(df2, new_person = pmin(person1, person2)), 
                 by = c('year', 'new_person'))
```

which gives

> ```
>   year person1.x person2.x   stocks new_person person1.y person2.y     bonds
> 1 2017       sam      mike 51482.66       mike       sam      mike  9562.717
> 2 2017     sarah     sally 49111.11      sally     sally     sarah  9057.971
> 3 2016     sally      ryan 58437.37       ryan     sally      ryan 11129.295
> 4 2016       kat       sam 45919.27        kat       sam       kat 10257.276
> 5 2015      ryan       sam 44734.43       ryan      ryan       sam 10154.195
> 6 2015     sally      mike 49002.75       mike      mike     sally  9398.425
> ```

**NOTE:** Make sure your variables are set `as.character`